# Using Nivoslider with Gumby

Tags: javascript, html, gumby-framework

I am trying to use Nivoslider with Gumby, but everytime I copy the code into my homepage, it just doesnt work. The demo works fine, I moved that across into the Gumby folder and works no probs, its just when I put it into a gumby page.

Has any one else had this problem?

Comment: Please provide details (your code etc.) or expect this question to be closed _soon_

Answer (score -1):

Check whether there is any URL for files like css, js. If it is web, download that file and use it in your local.